# Python array, getting every n entries, then moving onto the next n entries until the end of the array

Tags: python, arrays, function, for-loop, numpy-slicing

I have a 1D numpy array with 4,050,000 entries, I will call image_t. I am trying to slice it in such a way that I retrieve the first 10,000 entries, so image_t[0:10000], then the next step would be image_t[10000:20000] and so forth until it reaches the last slice.

This would end up giving me 405 different arrays, each of 10,000 entries. My problem is that I have tried many different kinds of loops and I am not sure what is going wrong.

I have tried:

Defining it as a function

```
def d_slice(S,step1):
    return [S[i::step] for i in range(step)]
```

This doesn't work because it returns 10,000 arrays of 405 entries each, meaning that it counts every 405th entry.

I tried a start stop inside the loop:

```
def s_t_slice(S):
    for i in np.arange(0,4050000, 10000):
        start = i
        end = i + 10000
        print(i)
        return S[start:end]
```

Here I hoped that if I told the array to slice the from i to i + 10000 it would do what I explained in the first paragraph. Unfortunately, the program dies after i = 0. Not sure why.

Next I tried creating an empty list of arrays 405 long and skipping the function.

```
im_array = [[] for i in range(1,406)]

for i in range(0,405):
    for j in range(0,4050000,10000):
    print(j)
    k = j + 10000
    im_array[k] = image_t[j:k]
```

This worked in that I managed to get 405 arrays of 10,000 entries each but the entries did not match the entries in the full array (i.e. im_array[0] was not the same as image_t[0:10000] and so forth).

I am pretty sure I am close to cracking it but I could use a hand as to what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use np.array_split(). the following code should work:

```
split_array = np.array_split(img_t, 405)
```

now split_array variable is a list of 405 arrays, each with shape of (10000,)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(4050000)
arr = np.split(405) # split the array up into sections
```

**Edit**:
Seermer's answer below will work as well. There's a key difference though, per the numpy documentation.

> The only difference between these functions is that array_split allows indices_or_sections to be an integer that does not equally divide the axis. For an array of length l that should be split into n sections, it returns l % n sub-arrays of size l//n + 1 and the rest of size l//n.

See [array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) vs [split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

For the sake of what you're doing, I would recommend using `split` instead of `array_split`.

Comment: Why would you recommend `split` instead of `array_split`?

Comment: Because OP most likely wants equal division. If you use split, it will raise `ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division` if you try to divide the array into some way that isn't equal. Where as array_split is doing modulo at the end to make it work.